# How can I ECHO in PHP the OK attribute in this SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, xml

How can I `echo` in PHP the OK attribute in this SimpleXMLElement?

I've been trying to figure this one out for hours but I can't solve it.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object(
    [@attributes] => Array(
        [OK] => No
    )
    [NEWS] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
        [NEWS] => Blocked
    )
)
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the manual, you'll see that there is an [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) function.

As long as you don't have any custom namespaces, you can simply call your XML object by `attributes`, then call the certain attribute by it's name.

```
echo $xml->attributes()->OK;
```

Should return `No`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're tripping up on the output of `print_r`, but the underlying XML for that example would be something like `<foo OK="No"><NEWS>Blocked</NEWS></foo>`, so OK is an ordinary XML attribute.

As the [manual's basic usage examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) show, the simplest way to access an attribute with SimpleXML is using `['attribute_name']`. So in your case, it will be like this:

```
echo $node['OK'];
```

Note that like all accessors, that returns another SimpleXML object, not a string, so if you're passing it around to other parts of your code, you should cast it to a string with the syntax `(string)` to avoid tripping up other code:

```
$ok_value = (string)$node['OK'];
```

As others have pointed out, there's also an [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method, which lets you loop through all attributes of a node, or access attributes which are in a particular XML namespace. These two lines are equivalent to the two above:

```
echo $node->attributes()->OK;
$ok_value = (string)$node->attributes()->OK;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result = [PUT OBJECT HERE]->attributes()->OK;
  echo $result;
```